# Building a regex to detect periods in the middle of a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, cocoa-touch, nsregularexpression

I am having trouble building my regex.

I want to be able to detect the following types of strings:

```
$T.CA
```

Right now it will detect $T but will ignore the .CA.

```
NSRegularExpression *symbolRegex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"(\\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)" 
                                                                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                                                                             error:nil];
```

How can I match this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to note :

You are using case insensitive match but you are supplying both a-z and A-Z in your character class. In addition your character class can be written as \w so the regex you actually need is as simple as this :

```
\\$\\w\\.\\w+
```

Comment: `NSRegularExpression *symbolRegex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"$\\w\\.\\w+"` doesn't work

Comment: I don't think so because my original regex works. Any thoughts?

Comment: I tested it and it works. I am not sure why it wouldn't work. Maybe $ is somehow specially escaped in objective - c?

Answer (score 2):

What you have:

```
$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

detects, as you said, $ and at least one character which is a letter or underscore.

You must add

```
[.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

to match the period and another group of letters or underscores (if it is what you want).

Comment: `NSRegularExpression *symbolRegex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"[.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+"` doesn't work

Comment: I mean the entire regex should be "$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+" I'm not familiar with Objective C so I'm not sure what characters you have to escape...

Answer (score 2):

what about

```
\\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

Comment: `NSRegularExpression *symbolRegex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"\\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+"` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
\$\w\.\w+
```

This regular expression do work correctly.
But i know little about object-c,you have to convert this expression to object-c string by yourself.

Comment: Stop linking to your site on every post, if this continues you will be banned.